# VBA code to work on ALL workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row       

If ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "FR_*" And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(4, 12), Cells(Lastrow, 12)), "<>Pending Distribution") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Warning, column L has values other than Pending Distribution"
    Cancel = True
End If

End Sub
```

It works when it is saved into the Workbook in vba but it doesn't work in Personal.xlsb

I want to make it work on ALL workbook that start with FR_ , but it is not working despite I am using ActiveSheet and ActiveWorkbook, why ?

Comment: You'll need to look at application level using an addin perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the personal like this should help

```
Public WithEvents CUSTOM_EXCEL As Excel.Application

Private Sub CUSTOM_EXCEL_WorkbookBeforeSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Lastrow = Wb.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row
If Wb.Name Like "FR_*" And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Wb.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(4, 12), _
    Cells(Lastrow, 12)), "<>Pending Distribution") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Warning, column L has values other than Pending Distribution"
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set CUSTOM_EXCEL = Application
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error, you need to use wb not activeworkbook in the sub

Comment: I did and still not working, where exactly this code should be placed in personal file, in ThisWorkBook or in a some module?

Comment: Error giving me in module "only valid in object module"

Comment: Personal file is in https://www.dropbox.com/s/7wjzsgqx4j627sg/PERSONAL.XLSB?dl=0  / code is in ThisWorkBook. Can you try it?

Comment: The error you are getting cant happen, are you definitely putting in Thisworkbook in Personal?

Comment: ^ shouldn't it be in ThisWorkbook of personal file?  This error is happening when I put the code in Module.

Comment: Where I am supposed to use the "CUSTOM_EXCEL" in my code?

Comment: Ok nevermind, It is working now - so I should always refer to Wb in everything.